# Xamarin Forms added web service is not working

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I added a connection service to my Xamarin.Forms project via WCF, then added these codes:

```
private async void NumberToWord(ulong num)
    {
        NumConvert.NumberConversionSoapTypeClient client = new NumConvert.NumberConversionSoapTypeClient(NumConvert.NumberConversionSoapTypeClient.EndpointConfiguration.NumberConversionSoap12);
        var result = await client.NumberToWordsAsync(num);
        labell.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```

But when I called this function it gives an error like this:

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'Element 'NumberToWordsAsyncResponse' with namespace name 'http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/' was not found. Line 4, position 6.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem while adding web service referance, checked the "Generate Synchronous Operations" checkbox on specifying the client options section:
[enter image description here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed6th.png)
[image]

With this you don't need to use only asynchronous functions but also synchronous ones too which is how i solved my problem.